# Azure AD - disable a client's application

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365-restapi

I want to create a service that can deny\revoke access to a user's mobile mail application.

To be specific, I want to temporarily **revoke access** to a **mobile mail client app** (like Nine) using **office365** online exchange mail, which is authenticated as an **Azure Active Directory** application.

So far I figured out how to do similar or partial actions:

- I can **manually** revoke azure AD apps using this link: https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/default.aspx

  But I didn't find an **API** for managing azure applications.
- I read through the 'Azure AD Graph API reference', but didn't find any way to delete, update a user's details or even to reset its password.
- I also looked at the office 365 API catalog, in which most of the APIs are for handling the user's contacts, calendar, mails etc... but no API for manging users. https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/api-catalog

Which API should I use in order to handle **outlook/AD users** or their **authorized applications**?

Comment: Did you have any problem about this issue? Please feel free to let me know if you still have any concern about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the application which integrate with Azure AD through OAuth 2.0, we can disable it as figure below through the new portal:

Switch your Azure active directory->All applicaitons->Select the application you want to manage->Properties->Set the option **Enabled for users sign-in** to **NO**.

We can also use the Azure AD Graph to change this option. Here is the sample request for your reference. And this rest require the permission of `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, we need to register an app and assign this permission to the app and login-in with the **admin** account.

```
PATH: https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{
     "accountEnabled":false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. is 'authorization' a header? part of the response? or something else?

Comment: It is the header of quest which enable the request pass the authentication. Refer [the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750)

Comment: Doesn't this disable the application for **all** users?

Comment: I tried it now and it actually worked (getting the principle showed accountEnabled equals false). BUT the Nine app can still sync with the  exchange server. any ideas?

Comment: Another update: It eventually did disable syncing. But it took a while (an hour or so...). How much time its supposed to take?

Comment: Based on my understanding, the application would still able to use the access_token to manage the resource protected by Azure AD after we disable the application. And the the life time of access_token normally last 1 hour. After the access_token expired the application would not able to get/renew the access_token since the application is disabled. And if you want the access_token also be revoked after you disable the application, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).