# Azure AD - Deleting an AppRoleAssignment didn't disable the application

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on a service which should be able to disable a user's app. That means for a specific office account, disable a specific application that authenticates against Azure AD.

In order to test my service I subscribed for 2 office 365 E1 accounts and an azure trial.

For testing disabling of an app, I downloaded [Nine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3) on one of my mobile devices and connected with my Office-365 account.

Then I queried the Azure Graph API with the following REST requests:

1. `GET <BASE>/users`

   And extracted my **user's ID** which I will denote as **[user-id]**

   (BASE = https://graph.windows.net/[tenant-id]/)

   (All my urls ends with api-version=1.6)
2. `GET <BASE>/servicePrincipals`

   And extracted the **Service Principal's ID** for the one that had appDisplayName: "Nine for office 365". Which I will denote with **[principle]**
3. `GET <BASE>/servicePrincipals/[principle]/appRoleAssignedTo`

   And received:

   > "odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/[removed]/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
   >   "value":[  {  "odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
   >        "objectType":"AppRoleAssignment",
   >        "objectId":"[**AppRoleAssignmentId**]",
   >        "deletionTimestamp":null,
   >        "creationTimestamp":"2017-01-01T17:04:45.1033993Z",
   >        "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   >        "principalDisplayName":"Tom",
   >        "principalId":"[removed]",
   >        "principalType":"User",
   >        "resourceDisplayName":"Nine for Office 365",
   >        "resourceId":"[**principle**]"
   >     },
4. And lastly -

   `DELETE <BASE>/users/[user-id]/appRoleAssignments/[AppRoleAssignmentId]`

   And received 204 as response code.

I queried again for the appRoleAssignment (As I did in section 3) and the one I deleted was actually removed, but, **Nine could still sync with server and receive new messages**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppRoleAssignment` is used to record when a user or group is assigned to an application. Delete this record will not disable the application. More detail about this entity, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity).

And to disable the application, I have answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328944/azure-ad-disable-a-clients-application). Please feel free to let me know whether you still have the problem.

### Update( the option to enable for users assignment)

[image]

Comment: I want to be able to **disable an app for a specific user**. I thought that the appRoleAssignment is the principal that gives the privilege for the app for that user. So what is the consequence of deleting it?

Comment: Yes, the **appRoleAssignment** is used to give the privilege to the specific user for the app. However this only works when you enable **User assignment required**, or all the users are able to access the app by default no matter the users are assigned or not . Please refer the figure in the post for this option.