# List groups which has access to Enterprise application AzureAD RBAC

Tags: python, azure, adal, azure-cli

I'm trying to use graph REST api / python of AzureAd.
I'm logged in with service principal.

Is it possible to list users/groups which has access to enterprise application?
If so: How?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-manage-assignments

Comment: OR perhaps put this in your favorite search engine: "azure list groups who have access python"  OR https://stackoverflow.com/q/30849305/125981 OR "azure list groups who have access python site:stackoverflow.com"

Answer (score 1):

Look in the RestAPI if you found what you need:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog

If you don't find it, it's likely not possible. If you found it, this RestAPI is exposed in Python by the `azure-graphrbac` package:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-graphrbac
- https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/activedirectory

If you found it in the RestAPI, but not in the Python package, open an issue for support to the endpoint your need:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I work in the Azure SDK for Python team at MS)

Comment: Thanks it looks like you are probably pointing right way and it looks like there are more APIs, I found the something in here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427063/azure-ad-deleting-an-approleassignment-didnt-disable-the-application?rq=1

I do not really mind how do I get the data, I just need the data :) - why I need it this way is the topic for different question
Unless there is better way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @laurent-mazuel I found the problem that [Navigation Properties are missing from SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/1926)

Workaround:
From documentation: [Service Principal Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity) has Navigation property `appRoleAssignedTo`. Then the solution was to use raw API endpoint as folows:
`https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/servicePrincipals/{service_principal}/appRoleAssignedTo/` and extend `ServicePrincipalOperations` in `azure-sdk-for-python`

Which returns AppRoleAssignment entities.